# Killing a python script in C#

Tags: c#, python, process, kill

I'm wondering if it's possible to kill a python script using C#.

In the small application I'm currently developing, a python application launches to localhost:portnumber. The portnumber of the application is always the same.

Is it possible, when the application is already running (I'm checking that by getting a list of ports currently in use), to kill it using some sort of command?

I've already found out that, in case it is not running, I can start the application using `Process.Start();`

Comment: which os is supposed to work?

Comment: I'm primarily developing it for Windows (hence the C# :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Process.Kill()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx)** to kill a specific process...
To find out *which* process to kill you can use `GetProcesses()` and itterate through them...

For example, here is how you can kill the calculator (calc.exe):

```
 foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => 
                                                         p.ProcessName == "calc"))
 {
     process.Kill();
 }
```

This will find all processes named "calc" and kill them.

In your case, If you already have a `Process` object (because you called `Process.Start()` ) you can specifically kill that one using the `Kill()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however the process(es) that started are both listed as 'pythonw.exe' in the taskmanager. There is no distinction between them aside the port number they are listening to. Would the above example still work then?

Comment: Almost, since you'll need the distinct `Id` property of the process. [Here is an example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box) of how to get the ProcessId based on the open port. You can use that and the example above to get what you want. (You'll want to use `p.Id` instead of `p.ProcessName`)